# Why I get remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string when I ran git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I am using Rails 4.0.0.rc2 and Ruby 1.9.3 I have created application and I have push that application at GitHub repository by using **git push**.

When I attempt the **git push heroku master** command I get the following error:

```
C:\Sites\first_app>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 101, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (92/92), done.
Writing objects: 100% (101/101), 21.02 KiB, done.
Total 101 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
remote:  !
remote:  !     There was an error parsing your Gemfile, we cannot continue
remote:  !     --- ERROR REPORT TEMPLATE ---------------------------------------------------
remote:  !     - What did you do?
remote:  !
remote:  !     I ran the command `/tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/bin/b
undle check`
remote:  !
remote:  !     - What did you expect to happen?
remote:  !
remote:  !     I expected Bundler to...
remote:  !
remote:  !     - What happened instead?
remote:  !
remote:  !     Instead, what actually happened was...
remote:  !
remote:  !
remote:  !     Error details
remote:  !
remote:  !     LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/b
undler/dsl.rb:166:in `group'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_2e1664b3e9f6ede5a8c91d27f6a70ce3/Gemfile:11:in `eval_gemfile'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:32:in `instance_eval'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:32:in `eval_gemfile'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:10:in `evaluate'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:25:in `build'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler.rb:155:in `definition'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/cli/check.rb:11:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:103:in `check'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:7:in `with_friendly_errors'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/gems/bundler-1.9.7/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/d20151213-205-1wyxt7v/bundler-1.9.7/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote:  !     Environment
remote:  !
remote:  !     Bundler   1.9.7
remote:  !     Rubygems  2.4.5.1
remote:  !     Ruby      2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
remote:  !     GEM_HOME  /tmp/build_2e1664b3e9f6ede5a8c91d27f6a70ce3/vendor/bundle
remote:  !     GEM_PATH
remote:  !     Git       1.9.1
remote:  !
remote:  !     Bundler settings
remote:  !
remote:  !     frozen
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "1"
remote:  !     path
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"
remote:  !     bin
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "vendor/bundle/bin"
remote:  !     jobs
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "4"
remote:  !     without
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "development:test"
remote:  !     disable_shared_gems
remote:  !     Set for the current user (/app/.bundle/config): "1"
remote:  !     gemfile
remote:  !     Set via BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "/tmp/build_2e1664b3e9f6ede5a8c91d27f6a70ce3/Gemfile"
remote:  !     --- TEMPLATE END ----------------------------------------------------------------
remote:  !
remote:  !     Unfortunately, an unexpected error occurred, and Bundler cannot continue.
remote:  !
remote:  !     First, try this link to see if there are any existing issue reports for this error:
remote:  !     https://github.com/bundler/bundler/search?q=no+block+given+%28yield%29&type=Issues
remote:  !
remote:  !     If there aren't any reports for this error yet, please create copy and paste the report template above into a new issue. Don't forget to anonymize any private data! The new issue form is located at:
remote:  !     https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/new
remote:  !
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to arcane-coast-8104.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/arcane-coast-8104.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/arcane-coast-8104.git
```

and when I using **heroku open** command

I got this page

[heroku open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgwSG.jpg)

what is going on?

How can I able deploy to Heroku?

Below is my whole gemfile source

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'    
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0.rc2'

#Add Bootstrap for pretty UI
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test] 
gem 'pg', group: :production
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production 

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0.rc2'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

#force for now
gem 'sprockets', '=2.11.0'

gem 'heroku', '~> 3.42', '>= 3.42.25'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

My localhost screenshot
  [localhost:3000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGSy4.jpg)

Comment: Possibly an error in your Gemfile (around line 11). Those are also some really old / odd versions to be using.

Comment: Below is my gemfile source around line 11, I didn't find any error

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do 
  gem 'sqlite3'
end 

group :production do 
    gem 'pg'
   gem 'rails_12factor' end

Comment: add your whole `Gemfile`

Comment: @Amr Noman I added my gemfile source.

Comment: Looks ok to me, does the application work fine in your local host? and did you make sure to commit before pushing to heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that you have a `.env` file in your Heroku environment, which contains a variable declaration with an unterminated string. This is evaluated by `dotenv` and causes problems with your Gemfile.

Comment: Wonderful. How do you fix it?

Comment: 1) locate your `.env` files 2) find unterminated strings 3) fix those.

Comment: how to  find unterminated strings?

Comment: Look for opening `"`s without matching closing `"`s.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had added a rake task that was requiring rspec. A rescue on LoadError needed to occur bc rspec was only in development and test, not production like this:

```
begin
require "rspec/core/rake_task"
  desc "Run all examples"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
    t.rspec_opts = %w[--color]
    t.pattern = 'spec/**/*_spec.rb'
  end
rescue LoadError
end
```

More documentation [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#rakefile)

Answer (score -1):

Just add the following gem to your gem file:

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```